# Can we measure data usage in Javascript for a web extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We are a group of students and we are attempting to develop a web extension (chrome) for a project.
We just discovered Javascript so we are noobs.
We'd like to develop a web extension which measures the data usage of the Internet browser.
We'd like to inspire ourselves of the Data Usage Extension which uses angular.module but we don't know if it's the right path to begin.
We spent a few hours to search what we needed but didn't find anything relevant.
Maybe some of you can help us with some ideas ?

Comment: There's no such API. There's a limited workaround via chrome.webRequest. You can see how the existing extensions for this task are doing it. You can inspect their code using crxviewer or the browser's built-in devtools debugger.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.